# Im trying to run JS code with npm run command but it cant find a module

Tags: node.js, npm, module

Im trying to run a piece of code but It cannot find a file which is there when I run it. The code works for other people just not me the error is:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\NFT\hashlips_art_engine-main/node_modules/sha1'Reqe_modules/sha1'Require stack:
- C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\NFT\hashlips_art_engine-main\src\mainn.js
- C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\NFT\hashlips_art_engine-main\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15) 
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\NFT\hashlips_art_engine-main\src\mainn.js:4:14)   \mainn.js:4:14)    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)   
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\jakub\\Desktop\\NFT\\hashlips_art_engine-main\\src\\mainn.js',    
    'C:\\Users\\jakub\\Desktop\\NFT\\hashlips_art_engine-main\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

I can send the piece of code if nescessary and the command is `npm run generate` or `npm run build`

here is the script part:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node index.js",
    "generate": "node index.js",
```

All necessary files that the command requires are where they should be as you can see here: https://dragster.cc/tA0GsSRC

Comment: Please edit your question to include the formatted output; as it is it looks like there's an error. A picture of a directory doesn't really help, although it doesn't show a `node_modules` directory, which would indicate that no install process was run.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton somehow I forgot to do the install proces, very weird but thanks for reminding me :) everything works just fine now